# How to configure Sitecore to index "everything but something" or "nothing but something"?

Tags: indexing

In one of the video from "Search Driven" module of Sitecore 9.0 Essential for Developers e-learning, the speaker says "You can configure Sitecore to index everything but something or nothing but something".

Could anyone please guide me on how to configure

1. to index everything but something
2. to index nothing but something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is referring to `IndexAllFields` in default index configuration file.

By default it is set to `true` which means it will index all fields.

There are settings that you can use in combination with above mentioned one:

- `<exclude>` - Excludes items from the index based on template type. 
  Excludes specific fields from the index, if `IndexAllFields` is set to
  `true`.
- `<include>` - Includes items from the index based on template type, if
  `IndexAllFields` is set to `false`.

So to achieve mentioned scenarios in your question:

- **to index everything but something not** - You need to have `IndexAllFields` set to `true` and in `<exclude>` node you need to specify what won't be indexed *in default index configuration file*
- **to index nothing but something yes** - You need to have `IndexAllFields` set to `false` and in `<include>` node you need to specify what will be indexed *in default index configuration file*

More information can be found here:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/the_search_and_indexing_configuration_files